# Why doesn't the addListener function of events class work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, single-page-application, serverside-javascript

I am new to node.js and trying to run this code:

```
var eventlib= require('events');
var emitter= new eventlib();

eventlib.addListener('MessageEvent', function()
{
    console.log('Registered the event');
});

eventlib.emit('MessageEvent');
```

but it doesn't work. It is throwing following error

> TypeError:  eventlib.addListener is not a function.

I am using version 8.11.3.

I have also tried **on** but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
eventlib.addListener('MessageEvent', function() {...});
eventlib.emit('MessageEvent');
```

to this:

```
emitter.addListener('MessageEvent', function() {...});
emitter.emit('MessageEvent');
```

---

You're trying to call `.addListener` and `.emit()` on the class instead of on the instance of the class that you created.